# Django wrong username, password for custom user model

Tags: python, django

I have created custom user model by using 'OneToOneField'. I have created the signup and signin system but only signup is working and I am able to register new user but, when I try to signin using that created user, Django is not allowing me to signin by showing my custom message 'Username or password is wrong'. I have double checked the username, password and it is correct but still Django is not allowing me to signin.

Here are my codes.

**models.py**

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 12, blank = True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignInForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'} ))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 15, widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'} ))
```

**views.py**

```
form = self.form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Your email address is not verified. Please verify it')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Username or password is wrong')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
context = {

    "form":form
}


if form.is_valid():
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")

    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        login(request, user)
        context['form'] = LoginForm()
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        print('Error')

return render(request, "MainApp/login.html", context)
```

1. You need to add the context dict for your form
2. Use the `is not None` conditional instead of `if user`
3. This line is to remove the key entered after the user submits form `context['form'] = LoginForm()`

I believe that could be the solution to your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately its not working. I found that issue is when I call the user.save() during the registration process. If I don't call this, then I am able to login but if I call this then it won't allow me to login. I'm calling user.save() because I want user.is_active = False.